# How do you bind custom attribute types to custom views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, android-attributes

I'm using data binding with my view models and views, and I'd like my custom view to observe my custom type, like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.myapp.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    ...

        <com.myapp.MyCustomView
            android:id="@+id/custom_view"
            app:thing="@{viewModel.customThing}" />. <!-- customThing is type com.myapp.MyThing -->
/>
```

In the above example, `viewModel.customThing` is a type that `MyCustomView` understands and expects. Can I pass it to my view this way? If not, is there another way to bind custom types to custom views in XML? I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: That looks OK, but when you say that you can't make it work what is happening? Is your custom view simply extended from another view or is it a compound view where you inflate the layout in your code? When you say "customThing is type com.myapp.MyThing" are you saying that it's a view? How is customThing defined in the view model? A little more detail may help get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make your custom view support data-binding.
There are two ways to implement this feature for your custom view.

### 1. [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)

For example, in your case

```
@BindingAdapter("thing") // attribute that you want to support data binding
fun setThing(view: MyCustomView, value: MyThing) {
    view.processThing(value)
}
```

But you should note that the binding adapter way can have a problem when previewing a layout in android studio.

### 2. Binding to setters

Let's assume that there is a layout that is called 'activity_main.xml' and that layout supports data-binding.
And There is a TextView widget in the layout.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/title
   android:text="title"
   android:enabled="@{true}"/>
```

If you see the class which is called `ActivityMainBindingImpl.java` generated by the data-binding library, you can see that `android:enabled="@{true}"` part is converted to `this.title.setEnabled(true);`

As you can see, the data-binding library is called its setters.
So if you want the thing attribute to support data-binding,
You can add a setter in your custom view class.

```
fun setThing(value: MyThing){
  // Do your stuff
}
```

When finishing added a custom setter, Place your cursor in layout editor in an attr "thing" and press `ctrl+b`(go to definition shortcut).
You can see that it connects with the setter you declared.